# Does git merge work against a remote branch?

Tags: git

While the `git pull myremote mybranch` works fine.. I can not discover how to do `git merge myremote mybranch`.

First here is the remote in question: `javadba` :

```
$ git remote
javadba
origin
```

Here is the remote/branch in question:  `javadba/memfix`.

```
`git fetch --all`
```

was just performed and found a bunch of remote updates. Note the current git repo is *presently* on that particular remote/branch:

```
   54ee844..5162513  memfix     -> javadba/memfix
* javadba/memfix
  master
  memfix
  remotes/javadba/master
  remotes/javadba/memfix
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/memfix
```

The following have been attempted:

`git merge myremote/mybranch` :

```
$ git merge javadba/memfix
warning: refname 'javadba/memfix' is ambiguous.
Already up-to-date.
```

`git merge myremote mybranch` :

```
$ git merge javadba memfix
merge: javadba - not something we can merge
```

`git merge` :

```
$ git merge
fatal: No remote for the current branch.
$ git checkout javadba/memfix
warning: refname 'javadba/memfix' is ambiguous.
M   bin/runservers.sh
M   bin/startStopServers.sh
M   tensorflow/GpuClient.scala
Already on 'javadba/memfix'
```

I have been through this exercise already on a prior set of remote updates: the `git pull` has the correct result .. but I had *already* done `git fetch --all` so that should not really be necessary .. ?

Two possibilities come to mind:

- `git merge remotebranch/localbranch` does not work the way I think
- there is something subtle amiss on my local git repo (but for which `git fetch` and `git pull` still work fine ??)

Any insights into either one of these?

Comment: Yes, you can merge with a remote tracking branch.

Comment: TL;DR  I had unintentionally created a branch `javadba/memfix` - and so the `git merge` command was not actually being applied to a *remote* branch at all: see the accepted answer.

Comment: I saw the answer after posting that comment. Glad you figured out the problem. I suggest you do some further reading about *remote tracking* branches which is the correct name for what you are calling a "remote branch". The difference is subtle but significant.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thx for the tip: will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git-merge` command takes as argument one (or more) branches (or tags, or commit hashes...) and merges those into the current branch.

So assuming that you are in the branch you want to merge into, this command should work to merge the remote branch.

```
$ git merge javadba/memfix
```

But, alas, it does not, because you have a local branch named `javadba/memfix`, so `git` does not know if you want to merge the remote branch `remotes/javadba/master` or the local branch `javadba/master`.
It is usually a bad idea to name a local branch starting with the name of a remote and a slash, maybe you did that accidentally?

In cases of ambiguity like this one, you can solve it by using the full name of the branch. That is the name of the file under `.git/refs`, starting with `refs/...`. For example, your command to merge the remote branch would be:

```
$ git merge refs/remotes/javadba/memfix
```

or to merge the local branch of the same name:

```
$ git merge refs/javadba/memfix
```

And you probably should delete that local branch, with:

```
$ git branch -d refs/javadba/memfix
```

Comment: `javadba` is the name of the remote : see the updated OP that shows the output of `git remote`.  Is your answer accurate given this information?

Comment: @javadba: I would say that I'm still right. The remote is `javadba` all right, but it does not prevent you to create a local branch or a tag with name `javadba/memfix`. It will just get confusing. You can double check with `git branch -a`. The usual output would have the remote branch `remotes/javadba/memfix` and the local tracking branch `memfix`, but I bet that you have also a local branch `javadba/memfix`.

Comment: well you're right. So then I have to re-trace my steps for creating the branches.  thanks and awarding.